# Remove a module from initadd under Solaris

Tags: unix, solaris

I accidentally added a non-existent module to my profile (or whatever it is you add it to) with

```
module initadd foo
```

and now every time I log on, I get an error message about `foo` not being found. How do I remove the module `foo` from the list, so I won't get the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
module initrm foo
```